# Asp.net invalid object name error when running query on SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a query, like the following:

```
SqlCommand putuser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MainDB(NumberofEmployees) VALUES(4)", cn);

putuser.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get an Invalid object name error for the table named MainDB.
I have checked the following:

1. The query works when running it in the Database.
2. I am connected to the correct database.
3. The Database does have a table with the name.

I am using Forms authentication. How do I make it so that anyone who access the application can make this insert to the Database. The insert is initially occurring after a user is created.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the message from the exception here.

Comment: What if you change it as `dbo.MainDB`, does it work ?

Comment: "How do I make it so that anyone who access the application can make this insert to the Database." If I understand correctly, this would be specified in the connection string: http://geekdeck.com/understanding-sql-server-connection-string/ (see Integrated Security).

Comment: Additional reading: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-do-i-get-object-could-not-be-found-or-invalid-object-name.html

Comment: I put dbo in front and still didn't work

Comment: put yourdatbase name  [Dbname].dbo.MainDB it seems you are connected to wrong  database or you may instaled the sqlserver  casesensetive , and in if you did you should use correct case for name

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a connection string with Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication?

If you are using SQL Server authentication, use:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1; Initial Catalog=DataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user; Password=password
```

then you need to make sure the user has access to the data base and schema that you are using.

If you are using Windows authentication, the use

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1; Initial Catalog=DataBase;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Persist Security Info=True;"/>
```

then you need to make sure that the user you are using in your App_Pool (the windows account that runs the application) is added as a login/user on the data base and has the rights to run queries.

EDIT

You can use SQL Server Management Studio to do this, step by step instructions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) and [here](http://support.gearhost.com/KB/a453/adding-users-to-mssql-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help, how exactly would I make sure a user has the right to run queries? Im using the management studio for MS SQL 2008.